# Use $\int_S f^{\pm} d\mu = \lim \int_S f_n^{\pm} d\mu$ to prove Scheffe's Lemma

Tags: probability-theory, real-analysis, measure-theory, integration, convergence-divergence

Let $(S, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure/probability space.

> **Scheffe's Lemma Part (ii)**: Suppose $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}, f \in \mathscr{L}^1 (S, \Sigma, \mu)$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(s) = f(s) \forall s \in S$ or a.e. in S. Then
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_S |f_n - f| d\mu = 0 \iff \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_S |f_n| d\mu = \int_S |f| d\mu$$

Use

$$\int_S f^{\pm} d\mu = \lim \int_S f_n^{\pm} d\mu \tag{*}$$

to prove Scheffe's Lemma Part (ii)

---

What I tried:

'only if': trivial

'if':

By Scheffe's Lemma Part (i) (same as (ii) except all functions are nonnegative) and $(*)$, we have

$$\lim \int_S |f_n^{+} - f^{+}| d\mu = 0$$

$$\lim \int_S |f_n^{-} - f^{-}| d\mu = 0$$

By Scheffe's Lemma Part (i) and assumption, we have

$$\lim \int_S| |f_n| - |f| |d\mu = 0$$

$$\to \lim \int_S (|f_n| - |f|)^{+}  d\mu = \lim \int_S (|f_n| - |f|)^{-}  d\mu$$

I don't suppose this means

$$\lim \int_S (f_n - f)^{+}  d\mu = \lim \int_S (f_n - f)^{-}  d\mu$$

does it?

If not, how else can I use $(*)$?

---

Edit: My attempt to prove $(*)$ without the assumption in 'if':

> **Fatou's Lemmas** for $f_n^{+}$
>
> $$\int_S \limsup f_n^{+} d\mu \ge \limsup \int_S f_n^{+} d\mu \ge \liminf \int_S f_n^{+} d\mu \ge \int_S \liminf f_n^{+} d\mu$$

$$\lim f_n^{+} = f^{+}$$

$$\to \limsup f_n^{+} = \liminf f_n^{+}$$

$$\to \int_S \limsup f_n^{+} d\mu = \int_S \liminf  f_n^{+} d\mu$$

$$\to \limsup \int_S f_n^{+} d\mu = \liminf \int_S f_n^{+} d\mu$$

$$\to \lim \int_S f_n^{+} d\mu = \int_S \lim f_n^{+} d\mu$$

Similarly, we have

$$\lim \int_S f_n^{-} d\mu = \int_S \lim f_n^{-} d\mu$$

Where is the assumption of 'if' used? It seems to give only that

$$\to \lim \int_S f_n^{+} d\mu + \lim \int_S f_n^{-} d\mu = \int_S \lim f_n^{+} d\mu + \int_S \lim f_n^{-} d\mu$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us prove

> Let $(S, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure/probability space. Suppose $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}, f \in \mathscr{L}^1 (S, \Sigma, \mu)$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(s) = f(s)$ a.e. in $S$. Then
>   $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_S |f_n - f| d\mu = 0 \iff \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_S |f_n| d\mu = \int_S |f| d\mu$$

**Proof**: (=>) It is trivial. In fact, 
$$\left | \int_S |f_n| d\mu - \int_S |f| d\mu   \right | \leqslant \int_S |\,|f_n| - |f|\,| d\mu  \leqslant \int_S |f_n - f| d\mu$$

For the (<=) part.

Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(s) = f(s)$ a.e. in $S$, we have that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n^{\pm}(s) = f^{\pm}(s)$ a.e. in $S$. Note that, for all $n$, $f_n^{\pm}$ and $f^{\pm}$ are nonnegative functions. Applying Fatou's Lemma, we have
$$\int_Sf^{-}d\mu\leqslant \lim\inf\int_Sf_n^{-}d\mu \tag{1} $$ 
and
$$\int_Sf^{+}d\mu\leqslant \lim\inf\int_Sf_n^{+}d\mu \tag{2}$$ 
We know that $f^{+}=|f|-f^{-}$ and, for all $n$,  $f_n^{+}=|f_n|-f_n^{-}$. So we have 
$$\int_S(|f|-f^{-})d\mu\leqslant \lim\inf\int_S(|f_n|-f_n^{-})d\mu$$ 
So we have, 
$$\int_S|f|d\mu - \int_Sf^{-}d\mu\leqslant \lim\inf\int_S|f_n|d\mu -\lim\sup \int_S f_n^{-}d\mu$$ 
Since, by the assumption of the (<=) part, we know that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_S |f_n| d\mu = \int_S |f| d\mu$, we get 
$$\int_S|f|d\mu - \int_Sf^{-}d\mu\leqslant \int_S|f|d\mu -\lim\sup \int_Sf_n^{-}d\mu$$
Since $ \int_S|f|d\mu <+\infty$ (because $f \in \mathscr{L}^1 (S, \Sigma, \mu)$), we get 
$$ \int_Sf^{-}d\mu\geqslant \lim\sup \int_Sf_n^{-}d\mu \tag{3}$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(3)$, we have
$$ \int_Sf^{-}d\mu= \lim \int_Sf_n^{-}d\mu \tag{4} $$
In a similar way, from $(1)$ and $(2)$, using $f^{-}=|f|-f^{+}$ and, for all $n$,  $f_n^{-}=|f_n|-f_n^{+}$, we can deduce 
$$ \int_Sf^{+}d\mu= \lim \int_Sf_n^{+}d\mu \tag{5} $$
So, combining $(4)$ and $(5)$, we have 
$$\int_S f^{\pm} d\mu = \lim \int_S f_n^{\pm} d\mu \tag{*}$$

Now, as you wrote: By Scheffe's Lemma Part (i) (same as (ii) except all functions are nonnegative) and $(*)$, we have

$$\lim_n \int_S |f_n^{+} - f^{+}| d\mu = 0$$

$$\lim_n \int_S |f_n^{-} - f^{-}| d\mu = 0$$

Now, note that  $f_n = f_n^{+}-f_n^{-}$ and $f=f^{+}-f^{-}$. So, we have
$$0\leqslant \int_S |f_n - f| d\mu = \int_S |(f_n^{+}-f_n^{-})- (f^{+}-f^{-})| d\mu \leqslant \int_S (|f_n^{+}-f^{+}|+|-f_n^{-} +f^{-})|) d\mu = \int_S |f_n^{+} - f^{+}| d\mu+ \int_S |f_n^{-} - f^{-}| d\mu $$
So, we have that 
$$\lim_n \int_S |f_n - f| d\mu = 0$$

Comment: Thanks Ramiro. Is the assumption used at all? It seems like $(*)$ implies both the assumption and the conclusion

Comment: @BCLC Ok. Those are two different questions: 

1. How we get from  $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_S |f_n| d\mu = \int_S |f| d\mu$ to  $(*)$? 

2. How we get from $(*)$  to  $\lim \int_S |f_n - f|  d\mu$?  

You asked question 2, and I answered question 2.  However to have a **complete** proof of the (<=)  part you must know the answer to question 1 as well.

Comment: Do you need the assumption to get to $(*)$? I think Fatou's lemmas are sufficient. I think from Fatou's lemmas I can prove the assumption, the conclusion and $(*)$

Comment: @BCLC Either using Fatou's lemma or Dominated Convergence Theorem you need the assumption to prove $(*)$.

Comment: @BCLC I edited my answer to make it a complete proof, including all the details. Please, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Wow. Okay I'll check out later. Thanks

Comment: Ramiro, I edited my question to show my attempt to prove $(*)$ without assumption of 'if'. what is wrong with it?

Comment: @BCLC Fatou's Lemma have conditions. Since, for all $n$, $f_n^{+}\geqslant 0$ (and $0$ is integrable) we can use Fatou's Lemma and we get: $$\liminf \int_S f_n^{+} d\mu \ge \int_S \liminf f_n^{+} d\mu$$ So we have $$\limsup \int_S f_n^{+} d\mu \ge \liminf \int_S f_n^{+} d\mu \ge \int_S \liminf f_n^{+} d\mu$$ HOWEVER, in order to get from Fatou's Lemma the inequality $$\int_S \limsup f_n^{+} d\mu \ge \limsup \int_S f_n^{+} d\mu$$ you need to show that there is an integrable function $g$ such that,  for all $n$, $f_n^{+}\leqslant g$. And you don't have it.

Comment: Ramiro, don't we? $\lim f_n^{+} = f^{+} = ... = \sup f_n^{+}$...? Ah so if the last equality doesn't hold, we don't necessarily have such $g$?

Comment: @BCLC You have that, for all $n$, $f_n^+ \leqslant \sup f_n^+$.  But... $\sup f_n^+$ may not be an integrable function.

Comment: Right. I forgot $\sup \ge \limsup$. Thanks Ramiro ^-^